# Control tick spacing in d3 line graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am currently implementing a line graph in d3 that needs to have equal spaces betwee custom tick ranges.

When using a linear scale, I can successfully build the scale with the necessary ticks but since the distance between each range of ticks is different I end up with something similar to this:

```
|-----------|-------|------|---|
5           15      19     23  25
```

I'm looking to achieve something like the following. This would have equal spaces between the custom ranges that I choose.

Ideally, I would like the graph to be able to contain any values between 5-25. The custom tick ranges should be equally spaced apart even though the amount of data points between them vary. I'm not sure what it takes to achieve this type of scale.

```
|----|----|----|----|
5    15   19   23   25
```

Any information is appreciated!

Comment: Use a point scale instead.

Comment: What if i have data points for every number between each of the ranges? Doesn't that make the scale like the original?

Comment: Wait, do you want to put the data points in the correct distance specified by their values? In that case, you want an axis divorced from the data?

Comment: Yes so in the above example, the second axis shown would allow data points in the range of 5-15, 15-19, 19-23, etc. but the ticks for each range would be consistently spaced from one another.

Comment: I suggest you update your question explaining this detail, including an explanation of *where* you expect the data points being positioned, otherwise nobody will be tempted to answer this.